# Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: java

Just I am trying to read the HTML file using URL. But getting the timed out exception.

source code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies","true");
        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: your code  working here . check your internet connection .

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me, please check your internet connection..